# Присвоить класс всем блокам

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
$('.ppd}').addClass('title');
```

С библиотекой удобно, сразу за раз присваиваем всем найденным блокам, заданный класс.

Вопрос, как это будет на чистом js. Возможно у кого уже есть готовый, оптимальный вариант?

Answer (score 1):

```
let h = document.getElementsByClassName("hello");
for(let value of h) value.classList.add("world");
```